# Reactjs Redirect Url Changes but component not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs. i have an problem with routing from external js file.

this is my navigation file code in top-header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Header(props) {
return  <div>
    <ul>
        <Router>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about-us">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contact-us">Contact</Link></li>
        </Router>
    </ul>
    </div>
     }
    export default Header;
```

and this is my main app.js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './utils/top-header.js';
/*pages*/
import Home from './utils/pages/home.js';
import Contact from './utils/pages/contact.js';
import About from './utils/pages/about.js';

function App() {
 return (
   <div>
    <Header />      
    <Router>        
    
    //this Link code works when directly added to app.js file//
    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about-us">About</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/contact-us">Contact</Link></li>

     <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about-us" component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="/contact-us" component={Contact}></Route>
    </Switch>
   </Router>
  </div>
 );
 }
 export default App;
```

i have checked by adding direct link in app.js file it is working but when the click link in header component not working.
**this is my output**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your Router(BrowserRouter) component only wrapping the Links, instead you wrap all Links, Routes, Switches in the  BrowserRouter component.

```
function Header(props) {
return  <div>
    <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about-us">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/contact-us">Contact</Link></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
}

function App() {
 return (
   <Router>
   <div>
    <Header />      

    //this Link code works when directly added to app.js file//
    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about-us">About</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/contact-us">Contact</Link></li>

     <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about-us" component={About}></Route>
        <Route path="/contact-us" component={Contact}></Route>
    </Switch>
  </div>
  </Router>
 );
 }
```

usually I will just put it in index.js, wrapping the App component

Comment: @PremKumar i removed the extra <Router> component inside, try again

Comment: @PremKumar please accept the answer if you think it helps